# Extra entry in Grub menu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, grub, bootloader, dualboot

My Toshiba laptop came with Windows 7 pre-installed. I installed Xubuntu on dual-boot (BIOS not UEFI). When Windows 10 came out, I upgraded to it, but now Grub shows two entries for Windows (besides the Windows Recovery Environment):

Windows 10 (on /dev/sda1)
Windows 7 (on /dev/sda2)

Windows 10 is installed on /dev/sda2 and there's no Windows 7 anymore.

I'm suspecting that the Windows bootloader is on sda1, but why is there a Windows 7 (which doesn't boot) and how do I remove the entry from Grub?

If I try to boot the Windows 7 entry I get a Windows Boot Manager screen saying:

> A recent hardware or software change might have installed a file that
> is signed incorrectly or damaged, or that might be malicious software
> from an unknown source.
>
> If you have a windows installation disc, insert the disc and restart
> your computer. Click "Repair your computer," and then choose a
> recovery tool,
>
> Otherwise, to start windows so you can investigate further, press the
> ENTER key to display the boot menu, press FS for Advanced Boot
> Options, and select Last Known Good. If you understand why the digital
> signature cannot be verified and want to start windows without this
> file, temporarily disable driver signature enforcement.
>
> File: \Windows\system32\winload.exe
>
> Status: 0xc0000428
>
> Info: Windows cannot verify the digital signature for this file.

I could modify the grub.cfg file manually or through Grub customizer to get rid of the redundant Win 7 entry, but this would be recreated the first time `update-grub` is run. How do I get rid of the grub entry **permanently**?

Comment: See if there's a `BOOTMGR` in sda2 and try getting rid of it?

Comment: How to do that safely, that is, without breaking the Windows installation?

Comment: I don't really see anything unsafe here. If there's already a different BOOTMGR and BCD on the other partition that is working and being used, then the one that is not is free to go. Either way, you can rename/move it and see if the `update-grub` still generates the useless entry first.